# Is there a formal relationship between graphs and probability distributions?

Tags: probability-distributions, graph-theory

Intuitively probability distributions and graphs are two different views on an underlying set of data.  Is there a formal description of the relationship between these two concepts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "two different vies on an underlying set of data," so if you give me a better sense of what you mean by each I might be able to describe different relationships.

One relationship between probability distributions and graph theory comes in the theory of finite Markov chains. The transition probabilities in such a chain give a weighted directed graph structure on the set of vertices.

Comment: In my (limited) understanding, graphs describe the relationship between things, vertices being the things, edges being the relationships.  Probability distributions also describe relationships, some things are statistically more similar and more likely to be related to others.  This is very vague I realize, I was hoping someone with a better understanding of both could guide me. ;)